# python library to access low-level detail of drive (SMART, scsi generic, ata security, etc)

Tags: python, linux, ioctl, scsi

Is there any python library to access low-level disk details?

I need:

- SMART attributes
- Serial number
- Firmware version
- SATA Phy counters
- SMART Extended Self-test log records
- Enclosure/letter/sg-device mapping
- ATA Security command access
- SCSI generic access (sg_inq, sg_format, etc)

Any ideas, outside of parsing output of smartctl, hdparm and sg3-utils?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if [this](https://github.com/rosjat/python-scsi) is of any help but you might get some of the point you mentioned done with it thought

Comment: Could you may provide some information about this Link instead of just a Link?

Comment: link to a github repository called python-scsi

Python classes to access SG_IO scsi devices

Comment: Thank you! Both of them cover 75% of everything I need.

Answer (score 2):

[pySMART](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pySMART/0.2) does at least some of this. It is a wrapper for smartmontools though.

Comment: thanks! It's better than parse it manually.